# Discount of Asian vs European vols

Tags: implied-volatility, european

I understand the discount for Asian vs. European vol depends on time to expiry and length of averaging period. This makes sense intuitively; a short averaging period far away blurs into a single expiry, while a close---but long---averaging period is very different from a bullet. Is there a rule of thumb to approximate that discount?